# Client not acknowledging sever emit event when client disconnects (user logs off) and connects again (user logs in again)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

The issue is that when a user logs out (socket.disconnect()) and logs back in everything looks fine, i.e. server detects a client connecting, can broadcast to all other users logged in, but when it emits an event back to the socket that just connected it's never detected by the client.  If a full refresh (F5) is done of the app after the user logs off and before logging in again all works perfectly.  I've tried using the 'forceNew' property in the connect() but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  I've also tried socket.io.disconnect() and socket.io.reconnect() but no luck either.

I'm don't know what else to try.  Anyone have a suggestion?

Using version 1.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the issue (probably more related to my being new to angular, but now it makes sense), I'll post it in case it helps anyone else.  The issue is that I have all socket related stuff in an AngularJS service, including the connection.  The way I had it structure was resulting the socket event listeners only getting attached the first time the service was injected, therefore on subsequent socket connects the event listeners were not.  All I had to do was wrap the socket listeners in a function and ensure that function was called after subsequent connects.